# How to refresh token after the access_token has expired

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I am using the [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) package in my laravel application for authentication. My AuthController looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\Providers\Auth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

class AuthController extends Controller {
    public $auth;
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('jwt', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $user = \App\User::first();

        auth()->byId($user->id);

        if (! $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        $token = \Auth::guard()->refresh();
        $user = JWTAuth::setToken($token)->toUser();
        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        $responseArray = [
            'access_token' => $token,
            'user' => new UserResource(auth()->user()),
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
        ];

        return response()->json($responseArray);
    }

}
```

And I have a JWT middleware, the `handle()` method of which looks like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    return $next($request);
}
```

And here are the routes:

```
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login')->name('login');
Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
```

The problem is I can only refresh the token as long as the access token is not expired. But what if I wanted to refresh the token after the access token is expired? Now it just throws TokenExpiredException when I hit the `/refresh` route after the token expiry. How can I refresh the token even after the access token has expired?

Comment: You can send a new token and keep a watch of tokens on front end and update it on your front end if there is a change. Sure that anybody could pass token and tamper it, but it would invalidate when server parses and authenticates it since JWT binds it with user_id anyway.

Comment: I did not understand. I need a way to keep my user logged in. So I need to update their token with the refreshed one. The problem is I cannot refresh it once the access token is expired.

Comment: what do you use in the front end? Angular or HTML,CSS, Javascript?

Comment: My frontend is a vuejs app. I log the user in, take the access token which has an hour expiry by default and keep it in the local storage. One hour later the user comes in and finds himself unauthenticated.

Comment: Put the code in a try-catch and when there is `TokenExpiredException`, catch it and do `JWTAuth::refresh($old_token)`. Now, a new token will be generated. Pass this to the client end. Since you are storing it in local storage, there you can do `if(localStorage.getItem('token') !== received_token){ localStorage.setItem(received_token) } `

Answer (score 0):

```
public function token(){
    $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
    if(!$token){
        throw new BadRequestHtttpException('Token not provided');
    }
    try{
        $token = JWTAuth::refresh($token);
    }catch(TokenInvalidException $e){
        throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('The token is invalid');
    }
    return $this->response->withArray(['token'=>$token]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are a couple of [issues](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/2056) related to the package

However, `refresh_token` has different lifetime than the `access_token` you can configure it in `config/jwt.php`.

You just have to make sure that your `refresh_token` is alive as well otherwise if both expires, then user has to request another token.

Another trick to do is to set this key to `null`, then `refresh_token` will have unlimited lifetime

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Refresh time to live
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the length of time (in minutes) that the token can be refreshed
    | within. I.E. The user can refresh their token within a 2 week window of
    | the original token being created until they must re-authenticate.
    | Defaults to 2 weeks.
    |
    | You can also set this to null, to yield an infinite refresh time.
    | Some may want this instead of never expiring tokens for e.g. a mobile app.
    | This is not particularly recommended, so make sure you have appropriate
    | systems in place to revoke the token if necessary.
    |
    */

    'refresh_ttl' => env('JWT_REFRESH_TTL', 20160),
```